# Fluent binding and conversions

Tags: data-binding, mvvmcross

When following the [Tutorial for TipCalc's iOS UI](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Tip-Calc-A-Xamarin.iOS-UI-project#binding-in-xamarinios), I noticed that the binding method described is obsolete(?) and decided to start using Fluent bindings like described [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Databinding#fluent).

Everything gone fine except for one thing: the iOS slider on the tutorial uses a `float` value between `0` and `1`, and the view model uses a `int` between `0` and `100`. So, obviously, I need a conversion here.

Since it's a two-way-binding, how can bind it to be converted for `ViewModel -> View` and `View -> ViewModel`? (ideally with fluent binding)

Also, I'd like to know how can I register a conversion under a "name" to later reuse it. Like it seems to be done on [this line](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ApiExamples/ApiExamples.Touch/Views/FirstView.cs#L565).

I tried to search on MvvmCross repos for these named conversions but I didn't find anything like a list of the available conversions, there is such a thing?

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Comment: please try to keep to 1 question per question if you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that the binding method described is obsolete(?)

The message attached to that method is:

```
   [Obsolete("Please use SourceDescribed or FullyDescribed instead")]
```

So use `SourceDescribed` if you only want to describe the source, or `FullyDescribed` if you want to describe the source and target.

```
   set.Bind(label).For(l => l.Text).SourceDescribed("'Hello ' + SourceText");
```

or:

```
   set.Bind(label).FullyDescribed("Text 'Hello ' + SourceText");
```

> Since it's a two-way-binding, how can bind it to be converted for ViewModel -> View and View -> ViewModel?

Two way converters implement both `Convert` and `ConvertBack`.

For example - see:

```
public class TwoWayConverter : MvxValueConverter<double, string>
{
    protected override string Convert(double value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (value*value).ToString();
    }

    protected override double ConvertBack(string value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        double doubleValue;
        double.TryParse(value, out doubleValue);
        return Math.Sqrt(doubleValue);
    }
}
```

from https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/ValueConversion/ValueConversion.Core/Converters/Converters.cs

> I'd like to know how can I register a conversion under a "name" to later reuse it

The names are registered by reflection and convention - see a full description in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#referencing-value-converters-in-touch-and-droid

> a list of the available conversions

MvvmCross doesn't provide many by default - these are mainly app things.

The only built-in converters that I know of are for:

- color
- visible
- language
- command parameter

All of these are discussed in https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#the-mvx-visibility-valueconverters